# miRNA analysis just using BLAST against mirbase.org

Tags: bioinformatics, rna

I have sequencing data (Illumina). Library prep was focused on short ncRNAs. I would like to identify human miRNAs. Do you think it is feasible to simply `BLAST` against a current version of [mirBase](http://www.mirbase.org) and filter the output for mature, human miRNAs without using `bowtie/tophat` against `hg19` first?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `TopHat` but it is better to use `bowtie` instead of `BLAST`. First of all you need to get rid of the adapter sequences (along with other processing steps prior to alignment).

Now there are two aspects here:

- miRNA quantification
- miRNA discovery

First one is relatively straightforward whereas the second one requires you to perform additional tests such as prediction of stem loops etc. There are published software that can handle both the aspects (`mirDeep`, `miRScan` etc). See [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2677885/) review for details on different miRNA gene finders. I have used [`miRdeep`](https://www.mdc-berlin.de/8551903/en/) and it uses `bowtie-1` to align.

`BLAST` would work but you have to set parameters which are suitable for small sequences (increase E-value cutoff, reduce word size etc). Moreover, `BLAST` does not have a cutoff option for the number of mismatches and the length of alignment (it only has a post alignment filter for percentage identity).

I also personally prefer `bowtie` because it has something called as `n-` alignment mode. In this mode the entire read is divided into `seed` and `non-seed` regions. You can specify the length of the seed region and the mismatch cutoff. Since for miRNAs the seed region (bases 2-8) is critical for its function, I generally set the `seed` mismatch cutoff to zero while allowing one or two mismatches in the `non-seed` region (note that in `bowtie` the `seed` always starts at 1).

In general, I would advise that you should go for `miRdeep` instead of `BLAST`. However, `miRdeep` doesn't straight away perform an alignment against the mature sequences. It maps the location of mature sequences in the pre-miRNA sequences (stem loops) and then aligns the reads to the pre-miRNA sequences. If the location of reads has a significant overlap with the mature region (you can adjust the window) then the read is considered as a valid miRNA.

Comment: Thanks alot. I would give bowtie a try first. So i set -N to 0. What value do you recommenf for -L (length of the seed substrings to align during multiseed alignment)?

Comment: @twckr you can set it to 10; I use 10. I set `-e` to 80. However, this is for the `fasta` file of the reads. The `e` option is for the max quality cutoff for mismatches. For `fasta` files the default quality is 40; so 80 means 2 mismatches. This would not be true if you use `fastq` files

Comment: I think a few mismatches in the miRNA seed might be tolerated regarding miRNA function, depending on their position.

Comment: @bli Seed is quite important. miRNAs are classified into families based on seed sequences. So, if your seed is different, it technically becomes a different miRNA. However, depending on the conditions and context seed mismatches (not exceeding two) may be tolerated.

Comment: Using `bowtie` I get quite different results compared to `BLAST`. Even setting the -L option to 22 (which should avoid any mismatches as far as I understood) I find significant differences in the results of both programs. Do you have an explanation for this finding?

Comment: @twckr You need to show me the files otherwise I cannot give an explanation. If the files are huge then just paste a section that shows the difference.